# Compactness - Norm on $\Bbb R^n$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, compactness

I am trying to prove the question below by Heine-Borel, $K_1$ and $K_2$ are subsets of $\Bbb R^n$.

Let $K_1 $and $K_2$ be two compact sets and A = $\{\lvert x_1 - x_2\lvert: x_1 \in K_1,x_2 \in K_2\}.$ Show that $A$ is compact.

**Proof:**

I am proving by Heine-Borel, therefore two steps.

First Step: show that A is bounded

For any $x_1 \in K$ and $x_2 \in K$, we know that $\lvert x_1 - x_2\lvert \leq  \lvert x_1\lvert + \lvert x_2\lvert$, as $\lvert x_1\lvert $ and $\lvert x_2\lvert $ are bounded the sum is bounded, so we are done proving that $\lvert x_1 - x_2\lvert$ is bounded.

Second Step: show that $A$ is closed

**I am not sure how to do the second step.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a sequence $(a_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ of points of $A$ which converges to some $a\in\Bbb R$; you want to prove that $a\in A$. Each $a_n$ can be writen as $|x_n-y_n|$ with $x_n\in K_1$ and $y_n\in K_2$. The sequence $(x_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ has a subsequence $(x_{n_k})_{k\in\Bbb N}$ which converges to some $x\in K_1$, since $K_1$ is compact. And the sequence $(y_{n_k})_{k\in\Bbb N}$ has some subsequence $(y_{m_l})_{l\in\Bbb N}$ which converges to some $y\in K_2$. But then\begin{align}a&=\lim_{l\to\infty}a_{n_l}\\&=\lim_{l\to\infty}\left|x_{n_l}-y_{n_l}\right|\\&=\left|\lim_{l\to\infty}(x_{n_l}-y_{n_l})\right|\\&=|x-y|\\&\in A.\end{align}

Comment: Very clear answer, I am not sure how I did not get that before.

Comment: I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 2):

The product of two compact subspaces is a compact. Therefore $K_1 \times K_2$ is a compact subspace of $\mathbb R^n \times \mathbb R^n$.

Then the application $(x,y) \mapsto \Vert x-y \Vert$ is continuous from $\mathbb R^n \times \mathbb R^n$ to $\mathbb R$.

As the image under a continuous map of a compact is compact, $A$ is compact.

Comment: I accepted the other answer because I do not know enough about continuity to understand/evaluate your answer.

Comment: @Beaba No problem at all. The answer from José is indeed more directly linked to Heine-Borel theorem.